# trying to create a new repo branch in vsts?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I've created a new MyRepo repo in VSTS via the "Version Control" tab. The "Repositories" left nav panel displays all of the repos for the currently selected project, including the repo that I just created.

No Branches are displayed for the repo that I just created but I thought that VSTS automatically added a "master" branch for new repos.  Did I miss a step when I created this new repo or should I create repos in a different way?

I don't see a way to create a new "master" branch for my repo via the Version control tab. When I try to search for the new MyRepo repo in the top right search bar widget, nothing is found.  Is there a broader, more consistent or better way to search for repos in VSTS?

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/organizations/projects/create-project?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav Do you have the right access on vsts? check with your VSTS admin to get yourself added into appropriate AD groups within your org.

Answer (score 0):

If you created an empty repo, then it's a *bare* repository. No branches, no files, nothing.

Navigate to the repo under the `Code` tab and you'll be able to initialize it with a `.gitignore` or a `README.md` file, which will create a branch.

Otherwise, clone the repo, commit some changes, then push it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I deleted the new repo but then recreated it and checked the checkbox to include a README file.  This auto-created a master branch for the repo and I was able to find the branch via a search after that.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with VSTS 2015, the "Explorer", "Branches" and "PullRequests" tabs on the page all showed the same content which gave no obvious option to "Create new branch". However, there was a button at the bottom of that page for creating a README file.  Clicking that created the master branch.

Hope this helps someone.